# Why was this question about the name "national socialism" deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, controversy

A new user [asked a question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/50476/where-the-nazis-actually-socialists) about why "national socialism" had the term *socialism* in their name. within 5 minutes it had 2 downvotes, 1 close-vote and was deleted, while I was trying to comment why this question might be actually worth answering, despite its negative perception.

So I wonder, why was it deleted so quickly? Did the OP himself remove it?

Answer (score 4):

The post author deleted the post himself - the downvotes and close votes were probably received because the post was poorly written, with typos in the title and a question body that lacks details.

If the post was undeleted, it should probably also be closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/37255/how-does-hitlers-interpretation-of-nationalist-socialism-relate-to-the-modern).

Comment: Ok, I expected there to be a similar question, but then, as you said, it should be closed as duplicate but not deleted. Thanks for the information, i was a bit confused there.